# How to prevent this Lua script from being sent over and over?

Tags: button, io, lua, command

I have a physical button I press in real life that shoots off this Lua script.  It works great, however, if I press and HOLD the button down, it sends the script over and over until I let go of the button.  What can I do to prevent this?

```
commandSent = 0
enableDebug()

while true do

--if input turns on and command has not been sent, send command
if io.input1 == 1 and commandSent == 0 then
httpRequest("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/axis-cgi/virtualinput/activate.cgi?schemaversion=1&port=1",50)
 print("input turned on")
 sleep(50)
httpRequest("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/axis-cgi/virtualinput/deactivate.cgi?schemaversion=1&port=1",50)
 commandSent = 1
end

--when input turns off, reset commandSent flag to 0
if io.input1 == 0 then
 print("input turned off")
commandSent = 0
end 
end
```

Comment: Which host environment are you working in here? What facilitates loading and executing this script, and changing the value of `io.input1`? How are `sleep` and `httpRequest` defined? We need more information to formulate any reasonable answers.

Comment: I am using the X600M from ControlByWeb.  It has built in controls through their web interface.  The above script just accesses those properties.

Comment: I'm not in your position, so I'm unsure of how to implement, but you basically want a debounce. When they press down, check if a variable "used" is true, if not, set it to true the and run code. If it is, do nothing. Now have another function designed for when they remove pressure from button, and set used to false in it.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.  Adding the word "local" to the script worked =)  See below:

```
local commandSent = 0
enableDebug()

while true do

--if input turns on and command has not been sent, send command
if io.input1 == 1 and commandSent == 0 then
httpRequest("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/axis-cgi/virtualinput/activate.cgi?schemaversion=1&port=1",50)
 print("input turned on")
 sleep(50)
httpRequest("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/axis-cgi/virtualinput/deactivate.cgi?schemaversion=1&port=1",50)
 commandSent = 1
end

--when input turns off, reset commandSent flag to 0
if io.input1 == 0 then
 print("input turned off")
commandSent = 0
end 
end
```